# Vertical Alignment within a logo slider

Tags: slider, vertical-alignment

I'm working on a site: http://new.a1asolar.com/ using a plugin in the footer for all the logos and I want to vertically align them to the middle and can't figure out how to do it.

My apologies but I'm not a coder per se. I just tweak to get the results I want. This is the CSS for the plugin:

```
#tchsp { height: 1%; overflow:hidden; position: relative; padding: 0 50px 10px;   }
#tchsp .viewport { height: ".$gal_height1."px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#tchsp .buttons { background: #C01313; border-radius: 35px; display: block; position: absolute;
top: 40%; left: 0; width: 35px; height: 35px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; line-height: 35px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 22px; }
#tchsp .next { right: 0; left: auto;top: 40%; }
#tchsp .buttons:hover{ color: #C01313;background: #fff; }
#tchsp .disable { visibility: hidden; }
#tchsp .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: ".$gal_width1."px; left: 0 top: 0; }
#tchsp .overview li{ float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; padding: 1px; height: ".$gal_height."px; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; width: ".$gal_width."px;}
```

---

So I removed the border with this:

```
div#tchsp li {border: 0px !important;}
```

but I'm unclear what tag(s) to target with the code suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add 3 lines to you css for `#tchsp .overview li` as shown

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items:center;
```

`flex-direction: row` is optional (default value) here.
[image]